# How add mavenCentral to gradle in dev of nativescript plugin

Tags: android, gradle, nativescript

I am writing a plugin for NativeScript but I have troubles with the gradle file, 
how can I add the mavencentral() to the repositories tag in buildScript and an "apply instruction" ? example:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
  }
}

apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I tried to add this to the include.gradle for my plugin but when I add this plugin in my app project, the build process fails.

Comment: I can advice only an extra solution to download a library and link to project

Comment: Can you please show the error message? Also I don't get your problem from your description - can you please be more specific what you want to achieve.